# How to create dynamic contract like we want to pass different name and symbol each time when we deploy contract

Tags: dynamic, solidity, contract

```
 constructor(string memory baseURI) ERC721(memory name, memory symbol) {
        _name = name;
        _symbol = symbol;
        setBaseURI(baseURI);
    }
```

We are calling this class from out script file to deploy contract

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `constructor(string memory baseURI, string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC721(name, symbol)`, then you can pass the name and symbol as a parameter of the constructor